# get »fingerprint« from rsa key

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa

By using the `crypto` module, it is easy to create a private/public key Pair in node. But how can I compute the »fingerprint« of a key?

[OpenCrypto](https://github.com/safebash/OpenCrypto) has something like that:

```
crypt.getFingerprint(key, options).then(function (fingerprint) {
  console.log(fingerprint)
})
```

What is the equivalent of nodes crypto module for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`OpenCrypto.getFingerprint`](https://github.com/safebash/opencrypto/blob/master/src/OpenCrypto.js) exports a public RSA key in the X509 DER format and creates a hash for these data. The same applies to a private RSA key with the difference that the private key is exported in the Pkcs8 DER format. The digest can be specified in the options (default: SHA 512) and also whether the data are returned as buffer or as hexadecimal string (default: hexadecimal string).

In the NodeJS code, keys can be generated with [`crypto.generateKeyPair`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypair_type_options_callback), whereby the key format can be specified explicitly. If the keys aren't already in the appropriate formats (X509 DER and Pkcs8 DER) key conversions can be performed to produce the *same* fingerprints that `OpenCrypto.getFingerprint` creates. Suitable functions for these operations are [`crypto.createPublicKey`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createpublickey_key) or [`crypto.createPrivateKey`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createprivatekey_key). Finally the hash has to be generated with [`crypto.createHash`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm_options).

**Update:**

The fingerprint is nothing else than a hash value, e.g. with the digest SHA-512 (as in `OpenCrypto.getFingerprint`):

```
var fingerprint = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(key).digest('hex'); // Fingerprint (hash) as hexadecimal string
```

where key is a public or private key in any format ([`string`, `Buffer`, ...](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_inputencoding)). If the key is given as X509 DER (public) or as PKCS8 DER (private), then the fingerprint *matches* that of `OpenCrypto.getFingerprint`.

If the key is in another format, the fingerprint can also be determined in this way. However, if the fingerprint *should match* the value provided by `OpenCrypto.getFingerprint`, the key must of course be converted into the formats used by `OpenCrypto.getFingerprint` before the hash is generated. This conversion isn't very complex, e.g. the conversion of a public PKCS1 PEM key (`publicKey`) into a X509 DER key (`publicKeyDER`) including the generation of the hash:

```
var publicKeyDER = crypto.createPublicKey(publicKey, { type: 'pkcs1', format: 'pem' }).export({ type: 'spki', format: 'der' }); // Convert a public PKCS1 PEM key into a X509 DER key
var fingerprint = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(publicKeyDER).digest('hex');                                               // Fingerprint (hash) as hexadecimal string
```

The bottom line is that these are functionally the same operations that are performed in `OpenCrypto.getFingerprint`. To my knowledge, there is no `OpenCrypto.getFingerprint` counterpart in the NodeJS `crypto` module. But with only little effort you can write your own function using the above `crypto` functions.

Comment: Thanks! hopefully that just sounds more complicated than it actually is :)

Comment: It's not that complex as it may seem at first glance, see the update section in my answer.